# how to create GridView/DataList with Editing Grid Column wise

Tags: c#, asp.net

Create on grid and which can be editable column wise rather than row wise editing.. i want to add columns in Grid dynamically(not fixed columns) and it can be editable. when Edit button click which will present at each column Header.

### Like

### Edit      Edit   Edit    Edit

```
   |Original | MOD1 | MOD2 | MOD3    ...
```

Cost1  | 500.00  | 550.0|550.0 | 1000.00 ...
Cost2  | 100.00  | 50.0 |150.0 | 500.00  ...

### Cost3  | 50.00   | 50.0 |50.0  | 100.00  ...

here when click on first Edit Link Original Column should be Editable.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the ReadOnly property of the column you wish to make editable whenever you click your "Edit" labels/buttons, where column->Index is an integer value within the range of the number of your columns:

```
dataGridView->Columns[column->Index]->ReadOnly = false;
```

Keep in mind you'll probably have to specify ReadOnly to be `true` whenever you add the column, as by default it's set to `false`, unless you specifically handle it a different way.